# If counselor of the Citadel was Anderson, would Cerberus attack Citadel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3, there's a mission where you need to save a Citadel from Cerberus attack.

The current counselor, Udina, selled out himslef to Cerberus.

If I choose Captain Anderson as the Counselor in ME1, would that change that situation?

Would Cerberus attack Citadel?

Answer (score 6):

No, choosing Anderson doesn't prevent this.

If you chose Anderson in Mass Effect 1, he steps down at the end of Mass Effect 2 because of all the bureaucracy and politics. Udina, who is experienced in those things, takes over as Earth's Councillor.